# failed android SDK update

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

When i'm trying to update the android SDK tools i'm getting below error: I tried so many methods but still same error.

```
Failed to rename directory C:\projectsdev\android\android-sdk\tools to C:\projectsdev\android\android-sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01.
[find_lock] Directory locked by adb.exe;cmd.exe;java.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from  [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4410#c38)

Best of luck!